# ymaps3 - Карта ре-инициализируется при любой манипуляции с DOM

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, nextjs

Пытаюсь сделать обертку для Yandex Map Api 3 для реакта.

Создаю контекст, в контексте через useSyncExteranlStore загружаю скрипт.
Получаю экземпляр `yamps` и `reactify`:

```
const YMapsProvider = ({
  apikey,
  lang,
  children,
}: YMapsProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const state = useSyncExternalStore(
    store.subscribe,
    () => store.getState(),
    () => ({
      reactify: null,
      ymaps: null,
    })
  );

  useIsomorphicEffect(() => {
    if (apikey) initializeAction({ apikey, lang });
  }, [apikey, lang]);

  return (
    <ymapsContext.Provider
      value={{
        ymaps: state.ymaps,
        reactify: state.reactify,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ymapsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Дальше внутри компонентов карт читаю контекст и выпускаю экземпляр компонента:

```
export const YMap: typeof YMapReact = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { reactify, ymaps } = useYMapsContext();
  if (!reactify || !ymaps) return null;
  const Component = reactify.module(ymaps)["YMap"];
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

С этим все хорошо, но любая манипуляция, например setState вызывает реинициализацию карты.
Через несколько манипуляций в окне браузера вылетает `warning`:

```sh
WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.
```

Пробовал создавать компоненты через useMemo, useCallback, createElement, forwardRef и т.п., передавать `yamps` и `reactify` как рефы т.п.

Судя по всему либо в контексте чего-то не хватает, либо...

Буду признателен за любые идеи

Репозиторий:
https://github.com/antokhio/next-ymaps3-issue

Постарался максимально убрать лишний код.